# How can I reference the ID of a separate html file using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul class="clearfix" id="cfix">
            <li class="icon" id="icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myMenu()">&#9776; 
                    Menu</a>
            </li>
            <div id="drop">
                <li><a href="index.html#about">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#resume">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#music">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#drop li').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to activate the class [selected] for my ID's referenced on a separate html file [index.html] from bio.html. The code above works while on index.html, but not for bio.html.

I tried adding `[href^='index.html#']` to the JQuery selector but to no avail.

How can I reference the ID of a separate html?

Comment: So sorry, didn't understand your question well. Can you please explain more on what you want exactly ?

Comment: Sure. How can I select an ID from a different page? For example, I want "#about" ID on the index page highlighted (selected class activated) when I click on it from the Bio page. Does that help?

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: cant you just write in the external js? and add the reference in all the html file that you need? store it in localStorage and read it back

Comment: @Se0ng11 You'll over-complicate things, what he needs is just to activate a class depending on pragma value (value after # in url)

Comment: @HammadiAgharass you might right, the question is not clear, I not really get what he trying to achieve, thought that he want to fire a click event from another page and update it on other page

Comment: @HammadiAgharass That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm testing your code right now and I think it'll work, but the document.location.hash refers to the URL, but I'm currently running on a test web server (my website is not hosted and released yet) so I'm not sure how I'll reference it

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake My code will work correctly in any case, it doesn't depend on if your website is online (hosted) or local (using wamp or file:// scheme).

Answer (score 0):

I repeat, I'm so sorry for not understanding your question despite that you made it clear at first.

To achieve what you're asking for, just add this to your index.html file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#drop").children().children("[href='index.html"+document.location.hash+"']").addClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. When I'm on bio.html and click on the ID's of index.html, it won't select it. It's the same as before.

Comment: Are bio and index in different tabs? Different frames? Different windows?

Comment: @JohnWu Different html files

Comment: I understand they are in different files. JQuery doesn't act on files; it acts on objects that are loaded into the browser. Are they both loaded? How?

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake The different html file needs a reference point from the window where the jquery is running. It would be most helpful to specify how that other html file is being loaded from the viewpoint of the DOM that the jquery is running in ... is it a parent? or a child? If it is a child it could be an ajax, new window child, or a iframe child, or? The reference would depend on its relationship to the jquery html page.

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake Possibilities include $("#drop li",parent.document), $("#drop li", window.parent.frames[0].document), etc, etc

Comment: @Wayne I'm sorry for being unclear for everyone. Still new to JQuery. As Se0ng11 said, I'd like to 'fire a click event from another page and update it on other page' or as HammadiAgharass put it: 'activate a class depending on pragma value (value after # in url)'. I'm not sure what the reference point would be in this case.

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake did the other page load this page (this meaning the jquery page), or did this page load the other page? Either way is valid, but changes the reference.

Comment: @Wayne Both pages load each other. It's like an ordinary navigation bar in a website except that first 4 'li' options all point to the same page with 4 different ID elements instead of 4 different pages.

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake From the browsers point of view, it loads the a URL this would be the parent. Does the parent then load this additional html as (an embeded iframe, ajax, popup window?) that would make the additional page a child document of the parent. Next, is the jQuery running from the parent, (original url file of the browser) or one of the child documents of the parent. And finally does #drop exist in one of the children, parent or sibling. Navigating multiple documents is possible, although more advanced and less common, so the jquery string pointing at it is a little more rare.

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake view-source:https://www.example.com/ shows the parent document's html if that helps clarify. Any additional html would be children of that html or that document.

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake I may be misunderstanding your question completely. Is what you want to do on the bio.html page is when the user clicks to the index page and it loads have one of the drop elements change? The CSS :target psuedo-class does exactly this.

Comment: @fluoridationMandrake Jquery itself can only change what is currently loaded not what will load in the future, but it can replace the say the entire body of the document with ajax and then modify the replaced document body - that would be done using an ajax call. So you would load the new html then modify. The script would of course need to be in the head section so it would not be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference a style from another html file.

You should instead write the style to a `.css` file and include that file in the `<head>` element of each page you want to use it in.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_css_file.css" />
</head>
```